# Targeting an Xbee using AT Commands Mode

Tags: xbee, mbed

I am trying to get one Xbee to talk to another. I understand that I can use `putc` to broadcast to all Xbees on a network but I want to target one specifically. I know that I need to use the hardware address on the XBee to do this and by using something called AT Commands mode but I don't think I understand it. For example, I have seen that to get into AT Commands mode I need to send '+++', however, I don't understand what to do. I tried this:

```
xbee.printf('+++');
```

but don't know where to look for some kind of message in response.

I don't understand this mode and can't seem to find anything which gives me an example for my situation or a relevant one.

I am using a normal Xbee on an FRDM-K64F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out.

To do this, you first need to do:

```
xbee.printf("xxx");
```

This puts you into AT Command mode and you can then run AT Commands. You need to wait at least 1 second before and after going into AT Command mode for this to work:

```
wait(1)
```

To send to a specific Xbee, you need it's 16-bit address and this can be found from the underside of the Xbee (although there is an AT Command to get this). The first 8-bits are the Xbee's high address (this is the same for all Xbees) and the second is it's low address and you need to set both of these using AT Commands before sending to the specific Xbee will work. To set these you must do the following:

```
xbee.printf("atdh 0013A200\n\r");
xbee.printf("atdl 12345678\n\r");
```

**You must do the `\n\r` part as this simulates an Enter button press which is needed to actually run the command.**

The atdh command sets the high address and the atdl command sets the low address. Once this is done, your sending Xbee will be configured to send to a specific Xbee and will not broadcast to all on the network. So when you now do:

```
xbee.putc('Y');
```

it will go to the Xbee who's address you have set.

You may have to wait 10 seconds after running those commands because I don't think I/O works in AT Command mode (I have not worked out yet how to exit AT Command mode yet but will update when I do).

Comment: If you're going to go to all of that trouble, you should consider running the XBee in API mode, and framing your data (adding headers and checksums).  There's an Open Source library for hosts to communicate with XBee modules in API mode, and I got it working on the one of the Freedom boards with mbed.  You might want to check it out: https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at that!